# How to connect pgBadger to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a database on a Google Cloud SQL instance. I want to connect the database to pgBadger which is used to analyse the query. I have tried finding various methods, but they are asking for the log file location.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are 2 major limitations preventing an easy set up that would allow you to use pgBadger with logs generated by a Cloud SQL instance.

The first is the fact that Cloud SQL logs are processed by Stackdriver, and can only be accessed through it. It is actually possible to [export logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/) from Stackdriver, however the outcome format and destination will still not meet the requirements for using pgBadger, which leads to the second major limitation.

Cloud SQL does not allow changes in all required configuration directives. The major one is the `log_line_prefix`, which currently does not follow the required format and it is not possible to change it. You can actually see what flags are supported in Cloud SQL in the [Supported flags documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres).

In order to use pgBadger you would need to reformat the log entries, while exporting them to a location where pgBadger could do its job. Stackdriver can stream the logs through Pub/Sub, so you could develop an app to process and store them in the format you need.

I hope this helps.